# bash while loop comparison not evaluating

Tags: bash, comparison, operators

I am trying to understand the difference between coding for `if` and `while` statements in bash.
In the script below, if I use `IF` I get the expected result using `==` OR `-eq` etc. However with the while loop each `while` seems to evaluate as true for all tests. While loops 1 & 3 should fail, correct?

```
A != B, 
A == B,
A == C
```

I have tried different combinations of `[ "" "" ]` or `[[ "" "" ]]` etc.

What is the correct syntax for `while`

thx
Art

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
myVarA="abc"
myVarB="abc"
myVarC="def"

while [[ ${myVarA} != ${myVarB} ]]
    echo "A does not equal B"
    i=$(($i+1))
    do sleep 1s
    break
done

while [[ ${myVarA} == ${myVarB} ]]
    echo "A does equal B"
    i=$(($i+1))
    do sleep 1s
    break
done

while [[ ${myVarA} == ${myVarC} ]]
    echo "A does equal C"
    i=$(($i+1))
    do sleep 1s
    break
done
```

renders the following,

```
+ myVarA=abc
+ myVarB=abc
+ myVarC=def
+ [[ abc != abc ]]
+ echo 'A does not equal B'
A does not equal B
+ i=1
+ sleep 1s
+ break
+ [[ abc == abc ]]
+ echo 'A does equal B'
A does equal B
+ i=2
+ sleep 1s
+ break
+ [[ abc == def ]]
+ echo 'A does equal C'
A does equal C
+ i=3
+ sleep 1s
+ break
```

Comment: The `do` part of your `while` loops are a few lines down the block. Possibly you should move them up to the beginning, i.e. `while [[ condition ]]; do`

Comment: @Tom, thanks for the lead, the answer below explained the wile condition extends until the :do and that I did not understand. thanks Art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `do` keywords are *wildly* misplaced.

Everything between `while` and `do` is the condition list.

So your condition list in the first block is

```
[[ ${myVarA} != ${myVarB} ]]; echo "A does not equal B"; i=$(($i+1))
```

which, as you might imagine, evaluates as `true` since `i=$(($i+1))` evaluates as `true`.

Similarly for the other blocks.

Move the `do` to the end of the `while` lines

```
while [[ ${myVarA} != ${myVarB} ]]; do
    : do something
done
```